# Seeking Spanish birth date and information for mason who died 1930 in Cuba

Tags: birth-records, spain, cuba

My grandfather Luis Urquia Estrada was a Mason in Santiago de Cuba.  He was born in Spain and moved to Cuba in his youth. I recently moved to Spain and need to find where and when he was born in order to apply for Spanish citizenship. Everyone in my family that might have this information has since passed. He passed away in 1938.

Comment: How old was he when he died?  Have you found an immigration record for him in Cuba?